# How to use params in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have a post controller saving posts with different attributes. There are attachments on the post as well. These attachments return just an id for the object. **my_cards**, **my_folders**, **other_cards** and **other_folders** are all such fields. These are defined as arrays in the model.

I am passing the right params from the form as shown below. All the correct data is present.

**PARAMS**

```
{"_id"=>"", "title"=>"Test Post Card attach 28", "description"=>"", 
"privacy"=>"public", "url_ids"=>"", "image_ids"=>"", 
"attached_card_ids"=>"", "my_card_ids"=>:my_card_ids, 
"my_folder_ids"=>"5d21dc7c616b656a9c030000", 
"other_card_ids"=>"5d1b1942616b656d10360000", 
"other_folder_ids"=>"5cfe2bdf69702d0aa3010200", "domain"=>"localhost", 
"controller"=>"api/v1/posts", "action"=>"create", 
"owner_id"=>"5d125102616b657131020000", 
"user_id"=>"5d125102616b657131020000"}
```

But when I save the post, the post_params method marks some fields as unpermitted even thought they are defined as arrays in the post_params method.

**POST-PARAMS**

```
Unpermitted parameters: _id, url_ids, image_ids, attached_card_ids, 
my_card_ids, other_card_ids, other_folder_ids, domain
{"title"=>"Test Post Card attach 28", "privacy"=>"public", 
"description"=>"", "owner_id"=>"5d125102616b657131020000", 
"user_id"=>"5d125102616b657131020000", "my_folder_ids"=>nil}
```

My post_params method looks like this

```
def post_params
  params.permit(:id, :title, :privacy, :description, 
   :owner_id,:user_id,
   :url_ids => [], :image_ids => [], :attached_card_ids => [],
   my_card_ids: [], my_folder_ids: [],
   :other_card_ids => [], :other_folder_ids => [])
end
```

I have tried multiple ways of defining an array in the post_params method after research on other Stack Overflow questions.

**EDIT**

I have managed to save the record in the Mongo database. The attributes look like this.

```
"my_card_ids" : [
        "5d1b83a6616b6523a9020000,5d1b9893616b653abd0b0000"
], 
"my_folder_ids" : [
        "5d21dc7c616b656a9c030000"
], 
"other_card_ids" : [
        "5d1b168c616b656d10140000"
], 
"other_folder_ids" : [
        "5cfe2bdf69702d0aa3010200"
]
```

They are being stored as strings, how can I save them as IDs, same as this

```
"collections" : [ 
        ObjectId("5d125102616b657131020000"),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you add HTML of the form you're using to post the form data.

The params you've displayed above show

```
"my_folder_ids"=>"5d21dc7c616b656a9c030000", 
 "other_card_ids"=>"5d1b1942616b656d10360000", 
"other_folder_ids"=>"5cfe2bdf69702d0aa3010200"
```

as strings. In the controller you have allowed them as arrays while you send them as plain strings.

To fix this, the html name attribute for the fields must be `name="my_folder_ids[]"` instead of `name=my_folder_id`

Comment: I was thinking it could be an issue of mismatching types from the HTML form. Let me try a few things and get back to you. Thanks